# What is the "time" for the Einstein feature in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

What is "time" in the Einstein feature of Marketing Cloud?

Is the time used by Einstein (e.g. STO) CST?
Or does it depend on the BU time zone?

Answer (score 0):

For STO / personalized send time optimization it does not matter what time zone is used. In other words if "my optimal time" is 4 am in the morning "Einstein time"  because I am in another timezone than Mr Einstein, that is absolutely fine.

For me, that might be 10 am.

==

For the dashboarding *view*, the setting is in the STO menu:

[image]

==

You can set this up via setup.

This setting can be defined at BU level.

[image]

==

In cases of insufficient data, Einstein's "optimal default time" analyses the entire account. This sounds like it could get wild in international orgs.
E.g. if there is a massive skew towards US data, people in Europe get their mails during the night as that's "typically a good time".

I guess here you'd better go with the alternative default option of "Send Immediately"

[image]